# SQLServer Проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: sql, база-данных

Параметры сортировки сервера: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. Параметры сортировки БД были изменены с `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` на `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`, но я по прежнему в полях вместо кириллицы вижу значения вроде `????????????`. Пробовал использовать в `INSERT` префикс `N` перед `''`, но результат тот же. Как корректно сохранять кириллицу в поля БД? Тип данных использую VARCHAR(N). Есть ещё одна БД на другом сервера, где параметр сортировки сервера изначально был установлен как `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS` и там поля с точно таким же типом данных спокойно хранят кириллицу, так что проблема мне кажется не в типе данных.

Comment: Не надо путать кодировку данных (charset) и параметры сортировки (collation). Изменение параметров сортировки никак не изменит кодировку имеющихся данных.

Comment: В таком случае мне нужно вернуть параметры сортировки в прежнее значение и менять кодировку данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете тип данных VARCHAR(N) в таблице, где N - количество символов, допустимых для хранения данных, и пытаетесь вставить строку формата NVARCHAR(N) в VARCHAR(N). Необходимо использовать тип данных поля таблицы NVARCHAR(N), если хотите вставить русские символы без "кракозябр", при этом предваряя строку символом N при вставке записей (N'Some text...').

> Всё это зависит от настроек операционной системы. Часто такая проблема
> с появлением "кракозябр" встречается на полностью англоязычных
> сборках.